# Android : Realm .so error

Tags: android, realm

I have business logic where I am inserting values in table per second for 10-15 mins. Randomly something going wrong with database and it’s not recording values in table (Records default value i.e. Zero). There is not specific logs or exception for this issue.

### Code Snippet is as below

```
realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
@Override
public void execute(Realm realm) {
try {
MyTable tableA = realm.createObject(MyTable.class);
tableA.setA(valueA);
tableA.setB(valueB);
tableA.setC(valueC);
tableA.setTimestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
});
```

https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/3160

Please check error image. This bug is coming randomly and I saw these error logs.

[image]